# ¿Como hacer una condicion para seleccionar un solo RadioButton existiendo dos RadioGroups en una sola Activity en Android Studio?

Tags: java, radiobutton, radiogroup

actualmente me encuentro programando una app en la aplicación andorid studio, lo que sucede es que quiero hacer 3 radiogroups cada uno con 2 radiobutton en una sola activity, pero quiero que solo se pueda seleccionar un solo radiobutton en la activity. Cuando formulo y ejecuto la app, me deja seleccionar uno por cada radiogroup
mi pregunta es, ¿como hago para que cuando seleccione un radiobutton y quiera cambiar de opción, no me queden dos radiobutton seleccionados? ayuda por favor

A continuación muestro el código que ejecuto

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RadioButton c1;
    private RadioButton c2;
    private RadioButton c3;
    private RadioButton c4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        c1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton7);
        c2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton8);
        c3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton9);
        c3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton10);

    }
    public void Dirigir(View view) {

        if (c1.isChecked() == true) {
            Intent suba1 = new Intent(this, Punto1.class);
            startActivity(suba1);
        } else if (c2.isChecked() == true) {
            Intent chapinero1 = new Intent(this, Punto2.class);
            startActivity(chapinero1);
        } else if (c3.isChecked() == true) {
            Intent Bosa1 = new Intent(this, Punto3.class);
            startActivity(Bosa1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que no grites a la gente cuando les pides ayuda. Me refiero a que en internet las mayúsculas son el equivalente a gritar! Además, deberías leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para evitar que tu pregunta reciba votos negativos o acabe cerrada, pues las preguntas que no muestran lo que hiciste dan muy mala imagen, además es imposible saber qué pasa cuando no podemos ver el código ni el error que da

Comment: Gracias Benito por el consejo, soy nuevo en esto y omití por accidente el propósito de las mayúsculas, leeré lo que aconsejas.
Por otro lado borre el código intentando otra cosa, volveré a dejarlo como estaba y lo subiré, gracias enserio por tu aporte y formulare mejor la pregunta y la volveré a subir

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es desactivar el resto cuando uno está seleccionado, por ejemplo:

```
radioButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    radioButtonDos.setEnabled(false);
                    Intent suba1 = new Intent(this, Punto1.class);
                    startActivity(suba1);
                }
            }
        });
```